# How I translate Python code into Julia code

Tags: python, julia, ijulia-notebook

I'm new in Julia and want this Python code translated in Julia.

```
def calcMarkov(preseq,propability,ordnung):
    betrachtungen = 0
    for pos in range(1,len(seq)):
        current = seq[pos]
        fromNode = seq[pos-ordnung:pos]
        if (fromNode == preseq and not current == "X"):
            propability[current] = propability[current] + 1
            betrachtungen += 1
    for key, value in propability.items():
        if(not betrachtungen == 0):
            propability[key] = propability[key]/betrachtungen
    print ("Anzahl der Betrachtungen:",betrachtungen)
    return propability
```

I Try this:

```
function calcMarkov(preseq, propability, ordnung)
    betrachtungen = 0
    for pos in 1: length(seq)
        current = seq[pos]
        fromNode = seq[pos-ordnung:pos]
        if fromNode == preseq != current == "X"
            propability[current] = propability[current] + 1
            betrachtungen += 1
        end
        for (key,value) in propability
            if(not betrachtungen == 0)
                propability[key] = propability[key]/betrachtungen
            end
        print("Anzahl der Betrachtungen:",betrachtungen)
        return propability
        end
    end
end
```

But I get an error message: syntax: missing comma or ) in argument list.

Can you tell me why? I am grateful for any help

Answer (score 6):

This line is not correct Julia syntax:

```
if(not betrachtungen == 0)
```

You should write:

```
if betrachtungen != 0
```

or

```
if !iszero(betrachtungen)
```

Even if you fix that there are some other problems:

```
if (fromNode == preseq and not current == "X"):
```

is not the same as

```
if fromNode == preseq != current == "X"
```

Instead, you should write

```
if fromNode == preseq && current != "X"
```

Furthermore:

```
for pos in range(1,len(seq)):
```

only iterates from 1 to `len(seq)-1` in Python, since ranges are non-inclusive at the end, while

```
for pos in 1: length(seq)
```

actually iterates from 1 to `length(seq)`. Perhaps you intended your python code to do this instead?

```
for pos in range(len(seq)):
```

This iterates from 0 to `len(seq)-1`.

Also an extra remark; it is much easier to help you if you can include a minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example